# sorting json file using python having value as string

Tags: python, json

i have json file:

```
ll = {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"James", "lastName":"Bond"},
    {"firstName":"Celestial", "lastName":"Systems"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
```

i want to sort by key(lastname or firstname)

i know the sorting method that we use with number as value but i am not able to sort this by value as string.

i tried below:

```
#data = json.load(file)
new = sorted(data, key = lambda k: k['employees'].get('lastName',0))
```

and getting error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give list of objects to `sorted` and `key` should be method to get value for single object.

```
In [1]: ll = {"employees": [{"name": "abc"}, {"name": "bcd"}]}

In [2]: sorted(ll['employees'], key=lambda x: x['name'])
Out[2]: [{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'bcd'}]
```

As you can see I get list of employees to `sorted`. Then `sorted` run `lambda` on every element of that list (so it calls `x['name']` on `{"name": "abc"}` and gets `name`. Then `sorted` sort elements in list using key (it doesn't matter if it's string or number - string are also numbers somehow - ascii).

When you have sorted list you can assign it to `ll['employees']` or any other place.

Anyway, guessing your code (cause you didn't include all of it) I assume that you're calling `sorted` on `dict`, not `list`. Also you're using wrong `key` (`k` is not full object, but single element in `list` passed to sorted).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the `ll["employees"]` list in-place using the `list.sort` method. And while you can roll your own key function using `lambda` it's cleaner and  more efficient to use `operator.itemgetter`.

In this code, my key function creates a tuple of the `lastName` followed by the `firstName`, so the list is primarily sorted by `lastName`, but people with the same `lastName` are sorted by `firstName`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

ll = {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Patti", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"James", "lastName":"Bond"},
    {"firstName":"Celestial", "lastName":"Systems"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}

ll["employees"].sort(key=itemgetter("lastName", "firstName"))
pprint(ll)
```

**output**

```
{'employees': [{'firstName': 'James', 'lastName': 'Bond'},
               {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe'},
               {'firstName': 'Peter', 'lastName': 'Jones'},
               {'firstName': 'Anna', 'lastName': 'Smith'},
               {'firstName': 'Patti', 'lastName': 'Smith'},
               {'firstName': 'Celestial', 'lastName': 'Systems'}]}
```